# MVC using the same connection string for every model?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

When I create a model in MVC I have to add a the same connectiong string entry for every model in the Web.config, is there a way around this?

Comment: You're going to have elaborate on that, since your question as asked makes no sense.  Your model has no relationship to your connection string, nor does your model have anything to do with your web.config.  So what exactly are you talking about?  Do you mean when you add an Entity Data Model?  And what do you mean by "you have to add the same connection string"   You don't have to add the same one, you can add any connection string.

Comment: When you create a new Model in Visual Studio 2013 you need to specify the DbContext connectiong string in your Web.config file, this seemingly has to be done for every new Model created even though all my Models use the same connection string.

Comment: @SebastianS Can you please list the steps that are leading to this? You should only be adding _one_ ADO.NET Entity Data Model to your project. All of the individual models will be defined inside there.

Comment: Rightclick on Models > Add > Class
Name it after the corresponding table

Repeat for every table in the database

Comment: At what point in the process of Right-Click Models > Add > Class are you being asked to specify a connection string? By "Right-Click Models", I assume you are referring to the Models folder in your VS project?

Comment: At no point, I create a class within the model inheriting DbContext that then links to a connection string that I then enter in the Web.config

Comment: Your models aren't supposed to inherit from DbContext. Can you please show us some of your code?